# Avoiding bad HTML to distort page

Tags: html

I am working on a web application where I read emails of an e-mail address (using pop) and store the html content of e-mail body in MS SQL Server 2012 varchar(max) field.

A functionality of website require me to display these stored emails inside a  tag held for that purpose.

The problem I am facing is that if an e-mail body contains bad HTML, it end up distorting the whole page. For e.g. if the e-mail body contains an additional `</div>`, it closes my main `<div>` tag (the one which is supposed to hold entire e-mail body) and the remaining HTML of e-mail body flows out of the holding area, becoming part of main page.

This application is coded in VB.NET and running on IIS 7.5.

PS: I tried searching for similar questions but couldn't find one. Please link me if this has been asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load external code in an iframe to limit its effect only to its context - not your application page.

Comment: Although its highly unlikely, but if the email body contain a closing iframe tag </iframe> will it still distort the page? I am just trying to be foolproof as my client is very demanding and do not want the application to fail no matter what.

Comment: No, it won't. The iframe content is completly independent from the outside tag. So the closing iframe is inside the email (in the iframe), and the iframe tag the user use is on the web page. These will be completly separated.

Answer (score 0):

Display the actual body of the email inside a separate `iframe`. Use the [new HTML5 attributes](http://webdesign.about.com/od/iframes/a/html5-iframe-attributes.htm) like `sandbox` to harden security.